# PDF Splitting error in debugging the code

Tags: python, debugging, pdf, split, deprecated

Good day, I have attached a code for pdf splitting that was created but is getting errors regarding the 37th line in the code. I am getting a deprecation error when debugging.

Error Message:
Exception has occurred: DeprecationError
reader.getNumPages is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use len(reader.pages) instead.
File "C:\Users\BrandonDelancy.BAHAMAS\Desktop\Mass Emails\Template\certificate_splitting.py", line 37, in 
while i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: reader.getNumPages is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use len(reader.pages) instead.

I have changed the line multiple times and still get the error regarding pdf.getnumpages or len(pdf.pages).

```
# PDF Certificate Splitting

# Import packages
import re
import time
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfFileWriter
from progressbar import ProgressBar
import fitz
import parameters
import sys

# Create paths
input_dir = parameters.inputs_foldername+'\Certificates'
try:
    os.mkdir(input_dir)
except:
    pass
output_dir = 'Outputs_'+parameters.batch_name+'\Split Certificates'
### Set up output folder
isExist = os.path.exists(output_dir)
if not isExist:
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# Get paths
count = 0
for path in os.listdir(input_dir):
    full_path = os.path.join(input_dir, path)

    pdf = PdfReader(full_path)

    t0 = time.time()

    i = 0
    new = True
    with fitz.open(full_path) as doc:
        while i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
            text = doc[i].get_text()
            
            if ("Page 1 of" in text) and (new == True):
                pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
                pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
                tmp = re.search(r"(?<=\*  \*  \*\n)\d{7}", text)
                parid = tmp.group()
                i+=1
                new = False
            elif ("Page 1 of" not in text) and (new == False):
                pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
                i+=1
                new = False
            elif ("Page 1 of" in text) and (new == False):
                with open(output_dir+'/'+str(parid)+'.pdf', "wb") as out:
                    pdf_writer.write(out)
                new = True
            else:
                raise ValueError("'Page 1 of' not found and 'new == True' at page "+str(i))  

        with open(output_dir+'/'+str(parid)+'.pdf', "wb") as out:
                    pdf_writer.write(out) 
    
    t1 = time.time()

    # Print timing
    print(str(pdf.getNumPages())+" pages processed in " + str(int(t1-t0)) + " seconds.")
```

Comment: Please attach the error message

Comment: Exception has occurred: DeprecationError
reader.getNumPages is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use len(reader.pages) instead.
  File "C:\Users\BrandonDelancy.BAHAMAS\Desktop\Mass Emails\Template\certificate_splitting.py", line 37, in <module>
    while i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: reader.getNumPages is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use len(reader.pages) instead.

Comment: Isn't it self explanatory?

Comment: The len(reader.pages) is still incurring errors of the property type not being callable

Comment: what `print(PyPDF2.__version__)` outputs? have you tried upgrading `pip install PyPDF2 --upgrade`?

Comment: PyPDF2 3.0.0 is the current installed version.

Comment: Then it should theoretically work when changed. But I'd also say `while i in range(...)` is not valid syntax and it should be `for i in range(len(pdf.pages))` instead

Comment: Thank you. I will continue to test this out to see if i can get a better understanding as I am still a beginner leveled in py and attempting to work towards fixing the issues. in the code.